# Extract POM version, for a job from Github Actions

Tags: github-actions, jib

I am trying to test with Github Actions to build my docker container automatically.

In my POM, the version of the docker image that I create with JIB, I extract it from the version of my project.

```
<groupId>io.xxx.my-proyect</groupId>
<artifactId>my-proyect</artifactId>
<version>0.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>my-proyect</name>
 ...

<plugin>
 <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
 ....
   <to>
    <image>XXX/my-proyect:${version}</image>
   </to>
 </plugin>
```

Github Actions:

```
- name: package
      run: ./mvnw package jib:dockerBuild
    - name: push
      run:  docker push xxx/my-proyect:VERSION (<-- Extract from version property of my POM)
```

Anyone have any idea how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ask Maven [using `maven-help-plugin`](https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/06/09/help-plugin/):

```
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout
```

If the command prints nothing (because `-q` suppresses all output including the evaluated version), then it's probably because the `maven-help-plugin` being used is too old. If so, you can pin the version like this:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:3.2.0:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout
```

Or, you could pin the version 3.2.0 in your `pom.xml` or in a parent `pom.xml` (if applicable).

Note that running a Maven command always takes some time, so it may add a few seconds to your build time. Passing `--offline` may help if it works (or may not so much).

---

Alternatively, you could run `jib:build` instead of `jib:dockerBuild` to have Jib directly push to `xxx/my-project:VERSION`. Looking at your YAML, there does not seem any good reason to run `jib:dockerBuild` followed by `docker push`. Using `jib:build` in this case will substantially cut your build time, as Jib loses a lot of performance optimizations when pushing to a local Docker daemon.

---

**UDPATE**: also, unless you are using Jib's `<containerizingMode>packaged` configuration, you don't need `mvn package`. `mvn compile jib:...` will suffice (and marginally faster).